# Selecting all visible selected options of a drop-down list using JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I need to select all the  Tags that are both selected and visible.

Is this the correct way to do it?

```
$('select option:selected:visible')
```

I believe it worked in the past, but apparently this returns undefined now. There is however a visible drop-down list with an option selected.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as I know you can only have a single selected option in any given select.  And yes, your selector should work perfectly.

Comment: I do have only one entry selected, but thanks for your answer, I guess the problem's somewhere else.

Comment: @John - you can have many selected if it's a `<select multiple>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$('select:visible option:selected')
```

I'm not sure if the options class as visible so that might be why you are getting no results.

Comment: hey, I have no idea what the problem was back then, but thanks anyway for your answer!

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `option:visible` is not supported. Or at least while the select is not expanded none of the options are technically visible.